# No route found in Shopware6/symfony

Tags: symfony, parameters, hyperlink, controller

following code will throw out error like this:

```
No route found for "GET https://tklustig.de/share/trade/action/" (from "https://tklustig.de/share/trade/download/")
```

What's the right way to intialize link with parameters in order to call php method in symfony?

Controller:

```html
#[NoReturn] #[Route(path: '/share/trade/action/{id}', name: 'frontend.action', methods: ['GET'])]
public function downloading($id): void
{
dd($id);
}
```

Link:

```
  $content .= '<a href="/share/trade/action/?id=5 "> Download </a>';
```

If I define route like this:

```
#[NoReturn] #[Route(path: '/share/trade/action/', name: 'frontend.action', methods: ['GET'])]
```

I will get error:

```
ould not resolve argument $id of "WtManageDownload\Storefront\Controller\DownloadController::downloading()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?
```

Parameter will not accepted, but i need it. I don't want to use POST.
In advanced thx a lot for each answer!